# SSH through bluetooth to raspberry pi using rfcomm. Nothing appears on bluetooth devices on my PC

Tags: raspbian, ssh, bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I followed https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/headless-raspberry-pi-configuration-over-bluetooth/

I see nothing on the bluetooth devices in my cellphone or computer. Here's the output of my raspberry pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-27 01:27:58 UTC; 4min 10s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 443 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─443 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jun 27 01:27:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 27 01:27:58 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: Bluetooth daemon 5.43
Jun 27 01:27:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 27 01:27:58 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: Starting SDP server
Jun 27 01:27:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jun 27 01:27:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Jun 27 01:27:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Jun 27 01:27:59 raspberrypi bluetoothd[443]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I also tried running `rfcomm` on the terminal but it returns immediately.

I also tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/bin/rfcomm watch hci0 1 getty rfcomm0 115200 vt100 -a pi
Waiting for connection on channel 1
```

but I still see nothing on the bluetooth devices. I waited 10 minutes and nothing appears.

**UPDATE:**

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmtJBc229Rg) which tells me to add a `-C` in front of the bluetooth service and also do this:

```
sudo bluetoothctl 
power on 
pairable on 
discoverable on 
agent on 
default-agent trust
```

Now I can connect to the raspberry pi but it stays connected for 1 second and then disconnects

**UPDATE:**

I tried pairing from my PC to the raspberry, and then from the raspberyr to PC. Both ways it pairs, then the two paires devices disconnect. It only connect for 2 seconds.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I followed https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/headless-raspberry-pi-configuration-over-bluetooth/ and I cannot stay connected for more than a second or two. Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @DeepakMittal nope, I never tried it anymore. If you figure it out, please post here to help me and others

Comment: I've seen you guys and another person complain about only being able to connect for a few seconds.